# Reuse a ViewController in Swift on iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift

I have a side menu with different navigation points. The first point is the Home nav. This should send the user back to the main view.

If I start the app, the main view will be generated by the storyboard. Now if a user taps on "Home", I would like to reuse this instance. Is this possible? (With Swift)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate a view from a storyboard like so:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let homeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home")
```

Then do as you will :)

Comment: yeah, I know that, but won't create this a new instance? Or will an already existing instance be reused?

Comment: Sorry ya that does create a new instance. You can try keeping a strong reference to the view controller in the AppDelegate, then you can present it again when you choose.

Comment: What I ended up with is to create a singleton with a variable (in swift vars are strong by default) when my main view controller is being created, I store a self reference into the singleton and then reuse it each time.
this is smooth and fast

Comment: You might also instantiate your view controller in AppDelegate and get it with UIApplication.shareApplication().appDelegate.myViewController.

Comment: hello, it is an old post, but i'm trying to do the same  and i'm stuck. i would like re-use viewcontoller without instanciate  it again after the first time , and show them to the user in the same state when he leaved. i does not use navigation controler and my controlers are called by presentviewcontroler (modale way). So i keep trace of my viewcontoler in array after when i get it in order to show to the user i have the error : Application tried to present modally an active controller. can you help me